# What is a simple command line tool for doing Needleman-Wunsch pair-wise alignment on the command line

Tags: sequence-alignment

I have two DNA strings:

> GGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGC

and

> AGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGG

I want a tool that allows me to do something like this on the command line:

```
$ aligner  GGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGC AGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGG
```

and receive an ASCII visualization of a pairwise alignment. Something like this would work:

```
GGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGC---------
---------AGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGG
```

I prefer a tool that is packaged on bioconda. A tool that also does protein and RNA sequences is even more preferable.

Comment: Is this a toy example? If so, maybe update it to another one. These sequences are low complexity and the actual correct alignment output is unclear to me

Comment: The sequences are not important. Edits are welcome.

Comment: To get the alignment in your example, you have to use zero (or very small) gap cost at the ends of sequences. That is not the standard NW.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true? To quote from the [EMBOSS package manual](http://bio.biomedicine.gu.se/cgi-bin/emboss/help/needle): 
"In a Needleman-Wunsch global alignment, the entire length of each sequence is aligned. The sequences might be partially overlapping or one sequence might be aligned entirely internally to the other. There is no penalty for the hanging ends of the overlap. In bioinformatics, it is usually reasonable to assume that the sequences are incomplete and there should be no penalty for failing to align the missing bases."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking for the `needle` program from the `EMBOSS` suite. Available in bioconda.

http://emboss.sourceforge.net/apps/release/6.6/emboss/apps/needle.html

To read sequences from the commandline, you need so specify the format as `asis`. To get the output on the screen, you'll need `-stdout` and to use the default alignment parameters (gap penalty 10, extend_penalty 0.5) you'll need `-auto`. Thus your query above would be:

```
$ needle -asequence asis:GGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGC -bsequence asis:AGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGG -auto -stdout
########################################
# Program: needle
# Rundate: Tue 27 Nov 2018 10:48:50
# Commandline: needle
#    -asequence asis:GGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGC
#    -bsequence asis:AGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGG
#    -auto
#    -stdout
# Align_format: srspair
# Report_file: stdout
########################################

#=======================================
#
# Aligned_sequences: 2
# 1: asis
# 2: asis
# Matrix: EDNAFULL
# Gap_penalty: 10.0
# Extend_penalty: 0.5
#
# Length: 56
# Identity:      37/56 (66.1%)
# Similarity:    37/56 (66.1%)
# Gaps:          18/56 (32.1%)
# Score: 181.0
# 
#
#=======================================

asis               1 GGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGC---     47
                              |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||.   
asis               1 ---------AGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAG     41

asis              47 ------     47

asis              42 AGGAGG     47


#---------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 9):

Install biopython with conda and use the following script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from Bio import Align
aligner = Align.PairwiseAligner()
aligner.mode = "local"
alignments = aligner.align(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
print(alignments[0])
```

The output is then:

```
.GGA-GGAGGGAG--AAGGAGGGAGGGAAGA-GGAGGGAG--AAGGAGGGAGGC
.|-|-||||||||--|||-|||-|||||-||-||||||||--|||-|||-|||.
AG-AAGGAGGGAGGGAAG-AGG-AGGGA-GAAGGAGGGAGGGAAG-AGG-AGG.
```

There are a LOT of alignments with that same score and you can tweak the details of the mode by changing `aligner.mode`.

Comment: yes, this should be pretty fast too since the alignment work is done in C (rather than python)

Answer (score 4):

I'd just use something like `t_coffee` and write a little bash function to run it on the strings you give:

```bash
aligner(){
  tmp=$(mktemp);
  args=("$@")
  for ((i=0; i<$#; i++)); do
    printf '>%s\n%s\n' $i ${args[i]} >> "$tmp"
  done
  t_coffee "$tmp"  2>/dev/null | /bin/grep -Pv '^CLUSTAL|^\s*$'
  rm "$tmp"

}
```

If you add that to your shell's initialization file (e.g. `~/.bashrc` if using bash on Linux, `~/.profile` if using bash on macOS), you can run `align2seqs` with as many sequences as you want to align:

```
$ aligner 'GGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGC' 'AGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGG'
0               GG--AGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGC
1               nAGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGG-GAAGAGGAGG
                    *********      *******  *********  * ** *  * 
$ aligner 'GAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGC' 'GGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGG' GAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGGATCCGAGGAAGAGGAGG AGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGCCCGAGATATATAAGGATCCGAGGAA
0               GA-GG----GAGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGG--AGGGAGGC
1               GGAGG----GAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGGAGGGAG-GGA--AGAGGAGG
2               GA-GG----GAGGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAAGGATCCGA-GGA--AGAGGAGG
3               AGAAGGAGGGAGGGAAGAGGCCCGAGATATAT--AA-GGATCCGAG-GAA
                    *    ***      **   **     *       *    * *
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option: https://github.com/noporpoise/seq-align; I've used it in the past as it is small and has no dependencies (just `make` and you're set).

Comment: This tool actually prompted my question! Do you know if anyone has packaged it?

Comment: Ah, no... I didn't notice the last part of your question.

Comment: Could you edit and include an example of how the OP could use this tool to do what they ask for? That will help future readers of this question.